# EditorConfig Timeout when searching .editorconfig for source file

Tags: java

I receive this message in InterlliJ EditorConfig Timeout when searching .editorconfig for source file disable. How do I enable EditorConfig in InterlliJ? I can't type in code in my project.

Comment: It seems that other people are experiencing the same issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-287750

I saw it as well in the Community Edition when I added an .editorconfig file to the project.
Maybe you could provide some information in the above mentioned ticket.